# After change input value it disappear immediately

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the text content or the value of a text input, So I added an event to write "hello" on a text input, it works, the problem is it disappear immediately and the text input change to empty.

```js
var monto_cliente = document.querySelector("#Monto_cliente");
var monto_caja = document.querySelector("#Monto_caja");
var btn_calc = document.querySelector("#btn_calc");
var tasa_dia = document.querySelector("#tasa_dia");
var select_tipo_cambio = document.querySelector("#Tipo_cambio");


btn_calc.addEventListener("click", () => monto_cliente.value = "hello");
```

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<title>Cambio de Dolares</title>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <form>
        <label for="Tipo_cambio">Seleccione el tipo de cambio: </label><br>
        <select name="Tipo_cambio" id="Tipo_cambio">
          <option>Dolares a Pesos</option>
          <option>Pesos a Dolares</option>
        </select>
        <label for="Tasa_dia">Digite la Tasa del dia</label>
        <input type="text" id="Tasa_dia">
        <label for="Monto_cliente">Monto Que tiene que dar el cliente</label>
        <input type="text" id="Monto_cliente">
        <label for="Monto_caja">Monto Que hay que darle al cliente</label>
        <input type="text" id="Monto_caja">
        <button id="btn_calc">Calcular</button>
      </form>
      


<script src="main.js"></script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Because you're submitting the `<form>` I imagine; try `<button id="btn_calc" type="button">` instead, so that it's "just" a `<button>` and doesn't automatically submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the default button type for most browsers is "submit" your form is submitted immediately after clicking the button. So, in order to avoid that from happening you could call `ev.preventDefault()` in your click event handler. Alternatively you could set the type to `button` in your button element.

Comment: This is the same answer as we have on thousands of questions like this. Please vote to close as a duplicate instead of answering.

Comment: I agree with you! :D - unfortunately I cannot delete it any more, as it is now the "accepted answer" ... :-(

Answer (score 0):

Form gets submitted When you press `button`. Either remove the `form` tag or change your button type to `button`:

```js
var monto_cliente = document.querySelector("#Monto_cliente");
var monto_caja = document.querySelector("#Monto_caja");
var btn_calc = document.querySelector("#btn_calc");
var tasa_dia = document.querySelector("#tasa_dia");
var select_tipo_cambio = document.querySelector("#Tipo_cambio");


btn_calc.addEventListener("click", () => monto_cliente.value = "hello");
```

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<title>Cambio de Dolares</title>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <form>
        <label for="Tipo_cambio">Seleccione el tipo de cambio: </label><br>
        <select name="Tipo_cambio" id="Tipo_cambio">
          <option>Dolares a Pesos</option>
          <option>Pesos a Dolares</option>
        </select>
        <label for="Tasa_dia">Digite la Tasa del dia</label>
        <input type="text" id="Tasa_dia">
        <label for="Monto_cliente">Monto Que tiene que dar el cliente</label>
        <input type="text" id="Monto_cliente">
        <label for="Monto_caja">Monto Que hay que darle al cliente</label>
        <input type="text" id="Monto_caja">
        <button id="btn_calc" type="button">Calcular</button>
      </form>
      


<script src="main.js"></script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: This is the same answer as we have on thousands of questions like this. Please vote to close as a duplicate instead of answering.